# Is there some easy way to change the wettability of a sphere?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, wetting

I am doing some experiments with spheres impacting a body of water and would like to change the wettability of the sphere.  Is there some relatively easy way to do this?  A procedure in one paper is extremely involved and in another they mention spraying it with something called SY-Supercoat-SHFC3150 and leaving it in a dust-free container for a few days.

However, this looks to be a product which is available in China: is there some very close alterative which I could buy which would do the same thing?

Comment: Perhaps WD-40 might work.

Comment: How big is the surface you are trying to cover, are these tiny sphere, like micro-spheres, are these in the milimeter range, the size of marbles/bearings, the size of ping-pong balls?
What do have access to, are you doing this in a lab or at home?
how much are you willing to spend?

You can increase wettability somewhat by faking it, instead of changing the sphere add soap to the water, this will change the surface tenstion and thus the wettability.
If you give a bit more of a clarification we can give a better answer.

Comment: The spheres are diameter 15mm stainless steel ball bearings.  I'm doing this in a lab and have funding.  The balls are dropped into a body of silicone oil, but I don't any more of the fluid at the moment so would prefer to change the wettability of the sphere directly if possible rather than doing anything to the fluid.

Comment: Are you wanting only to make it *less* wettable, or are you looking to cover a range of wettability as part of the domain of your experiment?

Comment: Just want to make a change to the wettability so I can isolate the effect of contact angle in our experiments (if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

certainly there is. At auto supply stores, you can buy something called RAIN-X liquid that you apply to the windshield of your car. This causes the surface to become unwettable, and rain drops that land on it will ball up into spheres and get blown off the glass by the wind.

The effect diminishes as dust and dirt get stuck onto the glass surface, but for the purposes of an experiment, it will work fine.

Comment: Looks as if this is already used in a few scientific papers to obtain hydrophobic surfaces anyway.  Thanks a lot, great suggestion.

Comment: I have realised that the only issue is that I am using silicone oil, RAIN-X is hydrophobic but not necessarily oleophobic.  Perhaps I could use spray with Teflon instead.